# Check availability does nothing when clicked

Tags: profile

CiviCRM 4.6.4 and WP4.2.2
I have a profile with 'Account creation required' checked and the profile displays the Username field OK but the 'Check Availability' function does not work.  It gives no error message, nothing.
Thoughts?

Comment: Start with the [js troubleshooting guide](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).